# Работа с блютуз в Cordova

Tags: android, phonegap, cordova, bluetooth

Пишу приложение на кордова и появилась потребность связать два устройства по блютузу и передавать данные (0 или 1). установил этот плагин - [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/tanelih/PhoneGap-bluetooth-plugin)

устройство видит, получаю его данные, даже проходит подключение. но когда пробую настроить поток, что бы по нему передавать данные - получаю ошибку.

определил, что есть 9 сокетов, некоторые из них вообще никак не реагируют, некоторые выдают ошибку

```
Connection lost, code 8
```

Может кто сталкивался, укажите куда копать

```
window.bluetooth.isPaired(
        function() {
            alert('Пристрій під\'єднано');

            window.bluetooth.getPaired(function (device) {
                var address = device[0].address;
                var name = device[0].name;

                window.bluetooth.getUuids(function (res) {
                    window.bluetooth.connect(function (res) {
                        alert('Вдало, '+JSON.stringify(res));

                        window.bluetooth.startConnectionManager(function () {
                            window.bluetooth.write(function () {
                                alert('Записано');
                            }, function (res) {
                                alert('Помилка, '+JSON.stringify(res));
                            }, 1);
                        }, function (res) {
                            alert('Помилка створення потоку, '+JSON.stringify(res));
                        });

                    }, function (res) {
                        alert('Помилка, '+JSON.stringify(res));
                    }, {"address": address, "uuid": res.uuids[2]});
                }, function (res) {
                    alert('Помилка зчитування данних, '+JSON.stringify(res));
                }, address);
            }, function (res) {
                alert('Помилка зчитування данних, '+JSON.stringify(res));
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            alert('Помилка'+ JSON.stringify(err));
        }, '00:45:DA:B4:07:BF');
```

Comment: 1. Сопряжение устройств.

2. Работающая программа на 2 устройствах.

3. Исходный код для понимания как вы запускаете подключение.

Comment: 1. два плантеша на 6 андроиде (xiomi)
2. вам предоставить программу?
3. добавил выше

Comment: Нужно чтобы устройства были сопряжены. Нужно чтобы программа работала одновременно на двух устройствах. Эти условия соблюдаются?

Comment: да, на их установлена программа

Comment: и да, они сопряжены

Comment: Ваш код получается пытается подключиться к устройству, но этот код одновременно работает на двух устройствах сразу (т.е. и там и там попытка подключиться)?

Comment: выходит что да, убрать на одном устройстве? или какой то другой код нужен?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75181/discussion-between-lampa-and-diefair).